# Java: how to ensure command-line compiling uses correct java version?

Tags: java

I'm transitioning from Java 1.6 to 7. It compiles, but gives an `incompatible types` error on my switch statement which is using a string (compiler complains that it should be an int type):

```
switch ("hello") {
   ...
}
```

thus, I don't think it's seeing version 7. However, when I type `java -version` I see:

```
java version "1.7.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_25-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)
```

When I type `javac -version` it shows `javac 1.6.0_30`. How to fix this?

Comment: Type `javac -version`.

Comment: @HotLicks hmmm, it shows `javac 1.6.0_30`. How to fix?

Comment: Type `echo %path%` and check out all the entries in the list.

Comment: When I (literally) type `echo %path%` it just returns: `%path%`.

Comment: Then type whatever the Linux equivalent is for `echo %path%`.

Comment: OK, I type `echo $PATH` and I see jdk1.6 folders and jdk7u25 folders. The jdk1.6 folders appear first.

Comment: So there's your problem.

Comment: Can you explain? Do I need to swap the order of appearance of jdk1.6 and jdk7u25? If so, how?

Comment: Unless you need it there for some reason I'd suggest removing 1.6 from the path entirely.

Answer (score 2):

Specify `-source 1.7` or `-target 1.7,` whichever suits you best. If it isn't a 1.7 compiler, either of these will fail before compilation starts.

Comment: What's the difference between source and target, and is this added as a switch in the command-line compiler text?

Comment: Both -source and -target give error: `javac: invalid source/target release: 1.7`.

Comment: -source says you're using 1.7 source code features, such as String cases. -target says you want that object code version, which means it won't run on 1.6 or earlier. The errors prove you're running a pre-1.7 compiler. You need to adjust your PATH.

Comment: How to remove those references to jdk 1.6 in my PATH variable?

Comment: On your undisclosed operating system? How would I know? How would anyone know? You're expected to be a competent user of your system. At least I expect it.

Answer (score 0):

But I found I can switch the order by modifying my .bash_profile file above from export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin to export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH, which solved the issue.